# Selecting a specific value of a column based on a value from another column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

| customer | shop | available_A | available_B | available_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A | True | True | False |
| . | B | False | True | True |
| . | C | True | False | True |

I want to only select True values of a specific "available" column based on the specific shop value, so something like:

```
select (available_A = 'True' where shop = 'A' AND 
available_B = 'True' where shop = 'B' AND
available_C = 'True' where shop = 'C')
```

All of them at the same script.

Comment: It may be useful to see the result you expect from this as the question make very little sense

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from shop where 
(shop = 'A' AND available_A = TRUE) OR 
(shop = 'B' AND available_B = TRUE) OR 
(shop = 'C' AND available_C = TRUE)
```

should do the trick. Although you should restructure your database to have a second table referencing the shop table storing availability.